# Python example for scipy dia_matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

Running this code

```
d0  = np.ones(N)
dp1 = np.ones(N - 1)
dm1 = np.ones(N - 1)

diag = [[d0],[dp1],[dm1]]
offsets = [0,1,-1]

A = dia_matrix( (diag,offsets), shape=(N,N), dtype=float)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dia.py", line 109, in __init__
self.data = np.atleast_2d(np.array(arg1[0], dtype=dtype, copy=copy))
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong! Can someone provide me a correct example to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the first argument of [`dia_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.html) has the form `(data, offsets)`, `data` is expected to be a 2-d array, with each row of `data` holding a diagonal of the matrix.  Since `data` is a rectangular matrix, some of the elements in `data` are ignored.  Subdiagonals are "left aligned", and superdiagonals are "right aligned".  (Specifically, the mapping between `data` and the sparse matrix `A` is `data[i,j] == A[j - offsets[i], j]`.)  For example, consider the following that will be used to create a 5x5 matrix:

```
In [28]: data
Out[28]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [29]: offsets
Out[29]: [0, 1, -1]
```

`data` contains three diagonals.  The since `offset[0]` is 0, row 0 of `data` contains the main diagonal.  All 5 elements in this row are used in the matrix.  `offset[1]` is 1, so the data in `data[1]` becomes the first superdiagonal.  Only the values `[7, 8, 9, 10]` will be used; the first value, `6`, is ignored.  Similarly, the third row of `data` gives the first subdiagonal, and only the values `[11, 12, 13, 14]` are used.

```
In [30]: a = dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(5, 5))

In [31]: a.A
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1,  7,  0,  0,  0],
       [11,  2,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12,  3,  9,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 13,  4, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 14,  5]])
```

Your example can be rewritten as follows:

```
In [32]: N = 5

In [33]: data = np.ones((3, 5))

In [34]: A = dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(N, N), dtype=float)

In [35]: A.A
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The `dia_matrix` docstring has another example.

Alternatively, you can use [`scipy.sparse.diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) to create the matrix.  This is useful if you already have code that generates the "correctly" sized diagonals.  With `diags`, you don't have to create the rectangular `data` matrix.  For example,

```
In [104]: from scipy.sparse import diags

In [105]: d0 = ones(n)

In [106]: dp1 = np.ones(N - 1)

In [107]: dm1 = np.ones(N - 1)

In [108]: d = [d0, dp1, dm1]

In [109]: B = diags(d, offsets, dtype=float)

In [110]: B.A
Out[110]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Hey, if I want to create an array full of zeros, except for the diag that has 1 repeated by a given shape (dimension). Is it better to have it with numpy or sparse matrix (in terms of memory)?